# Boot springboot app even if mongodb is down

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data, java-11

I am using **SpringBoot v2.7.0**

I have following springboot config

```yaml
spring:
  data:
    mongodb:
      uri: ${MONGO_DB_URL}
      database: ${MONGO_DB_DATABASE}
```

There is not explicit beans configurations. I have repositories for respective documents which extends `MongoRepository<ModelNameClass, IDType>`

This is all working fine. But now I want to handle the situation where i want to make sure that app still boots up if MongoDB is down. MongoDB is not our primary database.

How can i do so?

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB not being available wouldn't stop the app from starting successfully. Just tested this pointing the app to a local DB that didn't exist. There is below exception in the logs, but the app starts up and the test controller endpoint I added is accessible and responds correctly:

```
2022-08-13 07:08:10.093  INFO 14471 --- [localhost:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server localhost:27017

com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:70) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.6.0.jar:na]
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:180) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.6.0.jar:na]
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.lookupServerDescription(DefaultServerMonitor.java:193) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.6.0.jar:na]
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:157) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.6.0.jar:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) ~[na:na]
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
        at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:412) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:255) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:237) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:609) ~[na:na]
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStreamHelper.initialize(SocketStreamHelper.java:107) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.6.0.jar:na]
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.initializeSocket(SocketStream.java:79) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.6.0.jar:na]
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:65) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.6.0.jar:na]
        ... 4 common frames omitted

2022-08-13 07:08:10.204  INFO 14471 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.web.EndpointLinksResolver      : Exposing 1 endpoint(s) beneath base path '/actuator'
2022-08-13 07:08:10.230  INFO 14471 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2022-08-13 07:08:10.250  INFO 14471 --- [           main] io.github.devatherock.Application        : Started Application in 1.799 seconds (JVM running for 2.045)
2022-08-13 07:08:17.510  INFO 14471 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2022-08-13 07:08:17.510  INFO 14471 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2022-08-13 07:08:17.512  INFO 14471 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 1 ms
```

If what you mean is that the app's actuator health check is failing when mongodb is down, then the `MongoHealthIndicator` can be disabled by setting the below config:

```yaml
management:
  health:
    mongo:
      enabled: false
```

The test application can be found on [github](https://github.com/devatherock/spring-boot-demo/tree/spring-data-mongo)

Answer (score -1):

There is an option to ignore the initializing of `datasource` when your application fails to start by setting this property:

```
spring.sql.init.continue-on-error=true
```

You can read more about this fail-fast-feature on Spring Boot documentation which is [Spring Boot 2.7.0 Initialize a Database Using Basic SQL Scripts](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.7.0/reference/htmlsingle/#howto.data-initialization.using-basic-sql-scripts) which says:

> By default, Spring Boot enables the fail-fast feature of its script-based database initializer. This means that, if the scripts cause exceptions, the application fails to start. You can tune that behavior by setting `spring.sql.init.continue-on-error`.

Also if you want to handle when your database is down or up, you can create a `bean` for `datasource` and handle any exception which mean your database is down. In order to do this, create a class `@Configuration` which has `datasource` as `bean` like this:

```
@Configuration
public class DataSourceConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        try {
            // create datasource to your database 
        } catch (Exception) {
            // create a fake/dummy datasource to your database 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. `spring.sql.init.continue-on-error=true` this doesn't work in spring 2.7. 

2. for mongo db, you put settings in `spring.data` not in `datasource` so its not considered as `datasource` per say.